# Javascript find index of word in string (not part of word)

Tags: javascript, regex, search, indexof, text-search

I am currently using `str.indexOf("word")` to find a word in a string.
But the problem is that it is also returning parts of other words.

Example: "I went to the foobar and ordered foo."
I want the first index of the single word "foo", not not the foo within foobar.

I can not search for "foo " because sometimes it might be followed by a full-stop or comma (any non-alphanumeric character).

Comment: You have six questions which don't have accepted answers. Go back and accept an answer and people will be willing to post to this one.

Comment: Ok thanks I did not know I had a persistant account as "user759885", I have gone through and done so.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You'll have to use regex for this:

```
> 'I went to the foobar and ordered foo.'.indexOf('foo')
14
> 'I went to the foobar and ordered foo.'.search(/\bfoo\b/)
33
```

`/\bfoo\b/` matches `foo` that is surrounded by word boundaries.

To match an arbitrary word, construct a `RegExp` object:

```
> var word = 'foo';
> var regex = new RegExp('\\b' + word + '\\b');
> 'I went to the foobar and ordered foo.'.search(regex);
33
```

Comment: Had a go at making a general case but my implementation doesn't seem to be working. `reg = '/\b' + word+ '\b/'; str.indexOf(reg);`

Comment: If you want to compose the regex you need two steps: double scape the "\" ("\\b") and call the RegExp constructor: `reg = new RegExp("\\b" + word + "\\b");`

Comment: Ah, I see indexOf does not take regex so you have used `search()`. My final solution was to use `reg = '\\b(' + word + ')\\b';` `str.indexOf(reg);`

Comment: @user759885: See my edit. You'll have to construct a `RegExp` object.

Comment: Its not proper solution. for example, var word = '.'; var regex = new RegExp('\\b' + word + '\\b');
alert('I went to the foobar and ordered foo.'.search(regex)); it will give `0`.

Comment: @MMTac: JavaScript doesn't have an equivalent of Python's `re.escape()`, so the dot isn't being treated as a literal dot.

Comment: @Blender: Thanks for such a guidence.

Comment: @Blender FYI `\\b` boundaries in javascript do not work for non-English but otherwise perfectly alphanumeric characters like à, é, ö. `new RegExp("\\bestá\\b").test('¿dónde está la alcaldesa?')` returns `False`, but curiously `new RegExp("\\bdónde\\b").test('¿dónde está la alcaldesa?')` returns True.

Comment: @Growler did you know how to solve this issue you are talking about? I have the same issue on a translation script that's not working with the string "se acordó" because it has a "ó" at the end.

Answer (score 7):

For a general case, use the RegExp constrcutor to create the regular expression bounded by word boundaries:

```
function matchWord(s, word) {
  var re = new RegExp( '\\b' + word + '\\b');
  return s.match(re);
}
```

Note that hyphens are considered word boundaries, so sun-dried is two words.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried both with ".search" and ".match", as suggested in the previous answers, but only this solution worked for me.

```
var str = 'Lorem Ipsum Docet';
var kw  = 'IPSUM';
var res = new RegExp('\\b('+kw+')\\b','i').test(str);

console.log(res); // true (...or false)
```

With the 'i' for case insensitive search.

[ComFreek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/603003/comfreek) wrote a detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18740746/2903561)