# Search for a whole word in a string

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a function written in JavaScript (not in [jQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery)) which will return true if the given word exactly matches (should not be case sensitive).

Like...

```
var searchOnstring = " Hi, how are doing?"

   if( searchText == 'ho'){
     // Output: false
   }

   if( searchText == 'How'){
     // Output: true
   }
```

Comment: jQuery is JavaScript! (What you want is to not use it.)

Comment: and what if it is `Howl` ?

Comment: I don't want to include jquery library

Comment: This is easy with regular expressions.

Comment: Stop posting indexOf() answers!

Comment: @ComFreek Lol, I'd say about 80% of the 11 answers are `indexOf` :/

Comment: possible duplicate of [whole word match in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232934/whole-word-match-in-javascript)

Comment: @Doorknob The most downvotes I've ever given to answers of a single question. Very sad.

Comment: @ComFreek: but it was funny, wasn't it?

Comment: @zerkms It's funny that I have a reputation of 7777 now :)

Comment: @ComFreek: not anymore

Comment: @ComFreek Haha, I'm going to favorite this *just* for the deleted answers :D

Comment: @Doorknob Me, too, for the future time when I will have 10k Rep :D /zermks: You gave me an upvote, didn't you? -.-

Comment: @ComFreek: I wanted, but then I noticed it's not necessary.

Comment: @duffymo the last guy I heard saying something similar is missing now for 7 years already... :(

Comment: @pandita I recommend you playing this game: http://regexcrossword.com/ ;)

Comment: @pandita, now I'm worried....

Comment: @ComFreek there is something seriously wrong with this... but it's intriguing in a way at the same time. Maybe it really is not that hard... Maybe I just have a quick go at it!

Comment: @pandita It's not that hard as you may think at the beginning ;) If you need help, try [this bookmarklet](https://github.com/ComFreek/regex-cw-helper) (disclaimer: I'm the author).

Comment: @ComFreek hehe I was trying to be funny but will certainly check this out

Comment: @duffymo I just discovered that you used to do what I'm doing at the moment. Would you mind me asking you some questions outside of SO?

Comment: I usually don't.  What is that "something"?  Mech engr?  FEA?

Comment: No it's more about how you transitioned from mech to IT. I'm working on buildings/architecture atm. How did you jump? pandita.revolution@gmail.com

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could use regular expressions:

```
\bhow\b
```

Example:

```javascript
/\bhow\b/i.test(searchOnstring);
```

If you want to have a variable word (e.g. from a user input), you have to pay attention to not include special RegExp characters.

You have to escape them, for example with the function provided in the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) <sub>(scroll down a bit)</sub>:

```javascript
function escapeRegExp(string){
  return string.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
}

var regex = '\\b';
regex += escapeRegExp(yourDynamicString);
regex += '\\b';

new RegExp(regex, "i").test(searchOnstring);
```

Comment: it shows error like: Uncaught TypeError: Object function RegExp() { [native code] } has no method 'escape'

Comment: @anand4tech You have to include that function before calling my code. /Thanks Doorknob.

Comment: This escape function is directly taken from https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: @anand4tech See my edit, I used the escape function from MDN, now. /dystroy: Thanks.

Comment: @ComFreek, The value of ---new RegExp(regex, "i").test(searchOnstring);--- is coming  is always false

Comment: function escapeRegExp(string){
  return string.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
}
function myFunction()
{
var yourDynamicString='how Are you';
var searchOnstring='how';

var regex = '\b';
regex += escapeRegExp(yourDynamicString);
regex += '\b';
alert(regex)
var y= new RegExp(regex, 'i').test(searchOnstring);
alert(y)
}

Comment: @anand4tech 1. You confused *yourDynamicString* with *searchOnstring*. 2. One must escape '\' even in single quotes (my fault, sorry). 3. Please use semicolons. Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ydr3R/

Comment: Is the example valid JavaScript code (not a rhetorical question)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Which example do you mean exactly? Can you give me a hint on what should be invalid syntax? (I wrote this answer 9 years ago :))

Answer (score 3):

Here is a function that returns true with searchText is contained within searchOnString, ignoring case:

```
function isMatch(searchOnString, searchText) {
  searchText = searchText.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
  return searchOnString.match(new RegExp("\\b"+searchText+"\\b", "i")) != null;
}
```

Update, as mentioned you should escape the input, I'm using the escape function from https://stackoverflow.com/a/3561711/241294.

Comment: This is a link-only answer, which is discouraged. What happens if the link breaks? Your answer becomes useless. Also, we don't want people having to click *yet another* link after they arrive at SO. -1

Comment: @poida You should escape the `searchText`.

Comment: Now it's just wrong. And why are you checking for `null` anyway?

Comment: Did you try it? (better now because of escape. -1 removed)

Comment: @poida Removed my downvote, too, but one should really move the escape replacing into a function (I know, this is rather stylistic).

Answer (score -2):

Something like this will work:

```
if(/\show\s/i.test(searchOnstring)){
    alert("Found how");
}
```

[More on the test() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

Comment: Won't match `That's how.` string

Comment: No, he meant the string `"That's how."` (or `"How are you doing?"`)

Comment: Fair enough, I ran my test on the string provided and that was an oversight on my half.

Comment: @faino: if you provided a solution that works only for the predefined input - you could replace it with `return true;`

Comment: @zerkms @tckmn `That's how.` and `How are you doing?` aren't words. Why should they return true?

Answer (score -5):

Try this:

```
var s = 'string to check', ss= 'to';
if(s.indexOf(ss) != -1){
  //output : true
}
```