# Filter out Certain Words and Match only EXACT Words

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, filter, discord.js

I have an array of all stock symbols. When a user posts the message `'TSLA will open green tomorrow.'`, I want to detect the word `'TSLA'`.  But the problem is my code is also detecting `'T'`, `'S'`, and `'LA'`, since those are all valid stock symbols.

So I created a list of prohibited symbols consisting of every capital letter from `A` to `Z`.  But I don't know how to apply it.

```js
const url = 'https://dumbstockapi.com/stock?format=tickers-only&exchange=NASDAQ,NYSE,AMEX';
const bodyArray = [];
const blockedList = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.split('');

request(url, (error, { statusCode }, body) => {
  return error ? console.log(error) : statusCode == 200 ? bodyArray.push(JSON.parse(body)) : 0;
});

client.on('message', msg => {
  const { content, author: { tag } } = msg;
  const [arr] = bodyArray;
  const blocked = arr.indexOf(word => content.toUpperCase().includes(word) > -1);
  if (blocked.length) {
    console.log(`${tag} used a word in list.`);
    return msg.delete().catch(console.error);
  }
});
```

Comment: Your question seems unclear. Please provide examples of what you want to happen and what's currently happening.

Comment: @DaemonBeast i've updated

Comment: you could `forEach` the array, turn it into an object and just `object[stock]`

Comment: Your question is still unclear.  Do you receive keystrokes from the client?  Entire words?

Comment: @GirkovArpa keystrokes, and entire words. Someone could say TSLA will open green tomorrow. I want to detect the word TSLA in that entire message.content in Discord and start recording how many times a stock symbol was said on a server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Search whole word in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740664/search-whole-word-in-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `RegExp` to match every stock symbol in your list, but use the `\b` boundary symbol to prevent finding matches inside matches.

```js
const string = 'TSLA will open green tomorrow.  LA will too.';
const symbols = ['T', 'S', 'LA', 'TSLA'];
const regExpString = String.raw`\b`+ symbols.join(String.raw`\b|\b`);
const regExp = new RegExp(regExpString, 'gi');
const matches = string.match(regExp);

console.log(matches); // [ 'TSLA', 'LA' ]
```